# How to test HTTP/2 implementation on non-supporting browser?

Tags: nginx, https, http2

To implement HTTP/2 support on nginx/1.11.1, I'm going to redirect all HTTP Request to HTTPS.

In this case, how will Bot and Browsers, that don't support HTTP/2 protocol, behave and render the page?

Is there a way for me to simulate HTTP/1.1 browser behavior on Chrome Developer Tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing two concepts here that are somehow related, but they are largely different: HTTP to HTTPs redirect, and HTTP 1.1 vs HTTP/2 negotiation.

Redirecting HTTP to HTTPS requests is fine. Virtually every client (browser, bot, etc) available these days is capable of understanding HTTPS requests.

As for HTTP 1.1 vs HTTP/2, [Nginx will fallback to HTTP 1.1](https://giuseppeciotta.net/testing-nginx-http2-support.html) if the HTTP/2 connection fails because the client doesn't support it.

Last but not least, this question has very little to do with StackOverflow. It is more appropriate in ServerFault or SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

[Potentially interesting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head-of-line_blocking)

TCP retransmission will increase. This could lead on poorly configured devices for connection abort.